# How to Limit the Number of Characters in A JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

I have seen many solutions to the this problem but in every solution programmers used Document Filter Size . When I tried using it netbean compiler gives an error that class not found. I need to limit the user to a specified number of characters. Is there any other method that I can use to limit the JTextPane? Sorry for the very basic question as I am new to Java.

Comment: `" When I tried using it netbean compiler gives an error that class not found."` -- it's hard to help if you don't show pertinent code and the full error message. Please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see how this site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DocumentFilter` class has existed since JDK1.4. If you are using an old version then it is time to update to a newer version.

The `DocumentSizeFilter` class is NOT part of the JDK. It is custom code found in the Swing tutorials. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and download the code to your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only limit the max character size of a JTextPane via a `Document-Filter`. I suggest you update the `Java-Version` of your project in Netbeans.